# API call not working from tablet (Android)

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a native Android app that is being made for mobile and tablet. The API call in question is a GET request that uses basic authentication in the request header to send the user login details.

When I press the button the API call is sent, debugging shows that the request object is created fine and added to the request queue but then nothing happens.

I have checked the server logs and the API never makes it to the server. The exact same call on mobile works fine. Both devices are on the same wifi with no mobile data being used but tablet never gets a response, never times out and no errors are being shown.

I'm using volley for my network calls.

This is the code for the call:

```
public void GETbasicAuthentication(final String user, final String password, String URL, final VolleySingletonListener<JSONObject> listener, final VolleySingletonErrorListener errorListener) {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            listener.onResult(response);
            BaseActivity.printOut("GETbasic response", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            getErrorCode(error, errorListener);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s", user, password).getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE)));
            params.put("apikey", Constants.API_KEY);
            return params;
        }
    };


    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

/

```
public interface VolleySingletonListener<T> {
    void onResult(T object);
}


public interface VolleySingletonErrorListener {
    void onErrorResult(Exception error, JSONObject errorBody);
}
```

EDIT:
Following fiddler's comment I enabled `VolleyLog` and got the following:

```
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (143  ms) [ ] **REQUEST_URL** 0x3f39d365 NORMAL 1
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 1] add-to-queue
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [114] cache-queue-take
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [114] cache-miss
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [118] network-queue-take
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+142 ) [118] post-error
D/Volley: [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+1   ) [ 1] done
```

EDIT 2:

The request queue is initialised in the `NetworkManager` class:

```
private NetworkManager(Context context) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public static synchronized NetworkManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new NetworkManager(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static synchronized NetworkManager getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(NetworkManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                " is not initialized, call getInstance(...) first");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This is then called in the `onCreate` of the `Application` class:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance(this);
```

Furthermore, when an API call is to be made, the class is referenced like so:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().GETbasicAuthentication(...);
```

Check out my Gist to see the whole singleton set up in more detail https://gist.github.com/stoddayy/9e5b2cb429274947f8f5839546e05399

Comment: You could enable Volley debug logs with `VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks @fiddler I have updated my question

Comment: How do you initialize your `requestQueue` ?

Comment: @fiddler updated question again

Comment: @fiddler on looking at this again, the problem isnt with tablets but with older versions of android, i was testing on a tablet on API 17, tried again on API 21 and it worked fine, can offer any more fixes?

Comment: This can be due to TLS version supported by nginx